# Heroku create name already taken message after verifying account

Tags: heroku

I was creating a staging environment for an app which already had it's production environment set up in heroku. Following the Starting from Production App here - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments, I ran the command to create the staging environment:

```
heroku create staging-app-name --remote staging --addons mongohq:free,shared-database:5mb --account urban
```

Output:

```
Creating staging-app-name... done, stack is cedar
Adding mongohq:free to staging-app-name... failed
 !    Please verify your account to install this add-on
 !    For more information, see http://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/billing
 !    Confirm now at https://heroku.com/confirm
```

I visited https://heroku.com/confirm and got the message saying the 'Your account is verified'.

Went back to command line and re ran the create command. Output:

```
!    Name is already taken
```

When I go to heroku.com and look at My Apps, it is not there. How can I reclaim the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had ran the command under a certain account and was looking at My Apps in heroku under another :/ The app was there when I logged into the correct account.

Answer (score 2):

Contact support - this might be a bug in the CLI which you've uncovered.

Answer (score -1):

Please change name of the application. Because the name of the applications name is you typed are already taken by other user.So change your application name to avoid this error

Comment: This answer is a bit terse.  Try adding more explanation.